# Using weights formatted as a form element conflicts with ajax exposed filters

Tags: ajax, views

I created an admin view that filters content with taxonomy (using exposed filters). Nodes are ordered with `weight`.

[image]

When I load the block for the first time, I can change weights or drag and drop to reorder nodes. But when I apply a filter and then re-order I get the following output in plain (Drupal UI is gone) text in the browser window. Does any one know what happens here?

> [ {"command":"settings",
> "settings":{"basePath":"\u002Fgccadev2\u002F", "pathPrefix":"",
> "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"corporateclean",
> "theme_token":"J6qEwBHs0aYEghWy51Tx-Tm43ZKnLPc71r8ByaUSA74"},
> "colorbox":{"opacity":"0.85", "current":"{current} of {total}",
> "previous":"« Prev", "next":"Next »", "close":"Close",
> "maxWidth":"100%", "maxHeight":"100%", "fixed":true,
> "__drupal_alter_by_ref":[ "default" ]}, "equalHeightsModule":[
> {"elClass":"l1", "minheight":"", "maxheight":"",
> "overflow":"visible"}, {"elClass":"l2", "minheight":"",
> "maxheight":"", "overflow":"visible"}, {"elClass":"l3",
> "minheight":"", "maxheight":"", "overflow":"visible"} ],
> "lightbox2":{"rtl":"0",
> "file_path":"\u002Fgccadev2\u002F(\u005Cw\u005Cw\u002F)public:\u002F",
> "default_image":"\u002Fgccadev2\u002Fsites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Flightbox2\u002Fimages\u002Fbrokenimage.jpg",
> "border_size":10, "font_color":"000", "box_color":"fff",
> "top_position":"", "overlay_opacity":"0.8", "overlay_color":"000",
> "disable_close_click":true, "resize_sequence":0, "resize_speed":400,
> "fade_in_speed":400, "slide_down_speed":600, "use_alt_layout":false,
> "disable_resize":false, "disable_zoom":false, "force_show_nav":false,
> "show_caption":true, "loop_items":false, "node_link_text":"View Image
> Details", "node_link_target":false, "image_count":"Image !current of
> !total", "video_count":"Video !current of !total", "page_count":"Page
> !current of !total", "lite_press_x_close":"press \u003Ca
> href=\u0022#\u0022 onclick=\u0022hideLightbox(); return
> FALSE;\u0022\u003E\u003Ckbd\u003Ex\u003C\u002Fkbd\u003E\u003C\u002Fa\u003E
> to close", "download_link_text":"Download Original",
> "enable_login":false, "enable_contact":false, "keys_close":"c x 27",
> "keys_previous":"p 37", "keys_next":"n 39", "keys_zoom":"z",
> "keys_play_pause":"32", "display_image_size":"",
> "image_node_sizes":"()", "trigger_lightbox_classes":"",
> "trigger_lightbox_group_classes":"", "trigger_slideshow_classes":"",
> "trigger_lightframe_classes":"",
> "trigger_lightframe_group_classes":"", "custom_class_handler":0,
> "custom_trigger_classes":"", "disable_for_gallery_lists":true,
> "disable_for_acidfree_gallery_lists":true,
> "enable_acidfree_videos":true, "slideshow_interval":5000,
> "slideshow_automatic_start":true, "slideshow_automatic_exit":true,
> "show_play_pause":true, "pause_on_next_click":false,
> "pause_on_previous_click":true, "loop_slides":false,
> "iframe_width":600, "iframe_height":400, "iframe_border":1,
> "enable_video":false},
> "overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\u002F*\u002Fwebform\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fwebform\u002F*\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fwebform-results\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fwebform-results\u002F*\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fsubmission\u002F*\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Flinkchecker\u000Alinkchecker\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Amedia\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Amedia\u002F*\u002Fmultiedit\u000Amedia\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Frevert\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u002F*\u000Aoverlay\u002Fdismiss-message\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fshortcuts\u000Aadmin\u000Aadmin\u002F*\u000Abatch\u000Ataxonomy\u002Fterm\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Ftranslate\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fcancel\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u002F*\u000Ataxonomy\u002F*\u002Ftranslate\u000Ataxonomy\u002F*\u002Ftranslate\u002F*\u000Adevel\u002F*\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u002F*\u000Acomment\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u000Acomment\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u002F*\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u002F*\u000Ataxonomy\u002Fterm\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u000Ataxonomy\u002Fterm\u002F*\u002Fdevel\u002F*",
> "non_admin":"admin\u002Fstructure\u002Fblock\u002Fdemo\u002F*\u000Aadmin\u002Freports\u002Fstatus\u002Fphp"},
> "pathPrefixes":[ "fr" ], "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"}},
> "merge":true} ]

**EDIT**

I have tried using the Administration Views module and added the weight to the filters and got exactly the same issue

Comment: What you're seeing is JSON that's supposed to be picked up by core's ajax.js. How are you providing the drag & drop support? Does the reordering ever work? Should it use AJAX?

Comment: @Andy: the drag&drop support is provided by the weight module and re-ordering works when no filter is applied. AJAX is required by the exposed filters (they won't show id ajax is disabled)

Comment: [Perhaps the module doesn't support it?](http://drupal.org/node/920028).

Comment: There is a special field available in views just to do that. It adds the move crosses as well as the save button at the bottom of the table. I believe it's just a bug. The post you mentions is quite old already.